# Touch and hold to select text and save the text to redux in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

On a messaging app, when the user touch and hold on message, the user can select its words and show add button to save it to redux. How to achieve getting words from text component?

i have tried,
`<Text style={styles.name} selectable={true} selectionColor='orange'>{message}</Text>`

but it can only copy my text, i want custom selection button, where there is a '+' button on selecting the words